# facebook-ios-sdk modules successfully installed but not able to import

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode13.2

I followed the steps as suggested in the [official guide](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to install the packages using the Swift Package Manager and I manually selected the most recent release (currently [v12.3.1](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases/tag/v12.3.1)).

Even though autocomplete shows the modules, and the package has been added successfully to the Package Dependencies, when I try to import a module (e.g. `import FBSDKLoginKit`) I get the usual `No Such Module 'FBSDKLoginKit'`.

FYI I am currently using Xcode 13.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Go to project targets under the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section of the "General" tab and manually add the modules you need to import.

After searching around to the [official GitHub repo of facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), I discovered a note regarding [v5.11.0](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases?q=package+manager&expanded=true) saying the following:

> users must manually add the Accelerate framework to their targets under the the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section of the "General" tab

So I tried checking the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" and discovered that none of the Facebook modules I was trying to import were there, and therefore I manually added them.